# How can I limit number of hours a devices get on the network in my house?

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a Verizon G1100 router and can setup a schedule which restricts access (inclusive or exclusive) on a per-day basis which is great. Unfortunately this router lets me set a single schedule per device. Say allow (or disallow) access to a device from time X to time Y. However, I would like two other things if possible:

- Restrict time per day, e.g., max of two hours spread across the entire day whether early evening or late night. A fixed schedule of allowing 5-7pm is a bit too restrictive.
- Ideally, control this via an app (Android or iOS). This way if we want to allow more time to the kids after their limit expires then wife or me can control easily
- I can buy a new device or setup whatever software is required. I am hoping this can also become a project where I learn networking and/or anything else required if it isn't too complex..
- Something similar to airports would be great where once you connect, the system throws you out after 30 min.

Thanks much.